# PhoneGap app stuck in Portrait mode on Samsung Galaxy SIII

Tags: cordova, rotation, viewport, landscape, portrait

I just completed my first PhoneGap based Android app. HTMl5 with JqueryMobile. Works fine on most devices except on the Samsung Galazy SIII where the phone is stuck in portrait mode. I can't get it to rotate to landscape. I've been looking around SO and I'm not sure if I need to change settings in my meta viewport tag or somewhere in the manifest document.

Here's what I have for my meta viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no"/>
```

Any idea if that's right or what the fix might be for Samsung?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your manifest if you have android:screenOrientation="portrait" in your activity tag. That will fix the orientation to portrait.